# How can you search through multiple views?

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter, storyboard

So I have an app with a table view, that has a search bar. The table view has listed categories that can be narrowed down through the use of the search bar (just basic filter functionality). When a category is clicked, it goes to another view controller that has a discription of that category. The discription is done in fully in storyboard using multiple labels.

My question is, how can I use the table view search not only to search through the categories, but to also search the words in the related view controllers?

Ex: The table view has 2 categories, Numbers, and Letters. When Numbers is clicked it goes to the view that says "1, 2, 3". When Letters is clicked it goes to the view that says "A, B, C". So in the table view when "1, 2" is entered, the table view would be filtered to only show the Numbers category.

I will provide code for my table view, and one related view controller if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you must have to perform a search over your DataSource may be a dictionary or array.

Comment: @Gagan_IOS, so are you saying that if my data isn't arranged in some sort of a dictionary/array, then it cant really be done?

Comment: where is your datasource?

Comment: I wrote all the data directly into labels in storyboard.

Comment: ohh..you have to get all the data in your code not on the storyboard. Create a dynamic table with suited Datasource and perform search operation.

Comment: Ah alright. This might be harder then I thought then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controllers are not initialized before you click on a category and then for example numbers. That means you can not search the views through the depending view controller.

This comes from breaking the mvc concept. You are holding data in a view. This is not correct.

You need to hold your data for the view in a model (a dictionary for example), so you can search over it in your table view.

As a bad approach, you could try to instantiate the view and the controller while searching. - through the storyboard file. But this feels very ugly.

Comment: I do agree that there is a much better way of doing what I did, just through pure programming instead of relying heavily on the interface builder, but I'm a bit too far along to make these changes atm. I will look into the "bad approach", thanks.

Comment: You are not to far to fix this because this is just a replacement of the datasource. If you will not refactor this, it will come back 10 times harder at some point :)

Comment: So I would need to replace any labels that I have, with programmed labels and dictionaries supplying the data?

Comment: You can use your labels, but yes you have to connect them IBOutlets and provide them with data.

Comment: O alright, I understand what you are saying. Then it means that I'm already in the "10 times harder" phase :| Based on the scale of my project doing it that way would take a few months, although it seems the correct method.

Comment: So it is 100 view controllers project from your another question? :)

Comment: Lol yes, I picked the worst way to do it. But its almost done and works perfectly. Might have to update the search function another day. I will go ahead and mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: Ok, so normally i dont do that, but if this is a customer project and you have to give the code to the customer, put it into a private git and I refactor the code with you if you want.

Comment: I do really appreciate the offer, but I should be alright. Thanks.